# Step definition for drop down list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

I want to write step in Cucumber Scenario for selecting option "Grandfather's middle Name"
from drop down list of security_questions.

```
 <td align="left">
        <select id="security_question" class="sign-up-security Signup_red_text" name="user_detail[secret_question]">
        <option value="Please Select"> Please Select</option>
        <option value="grandfather middle name"> Grandfather's middle Name</option>
        <option value="first date last name"> First Date's Last Name</option>
        <option value="favorite place"> Favorite Place</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div id="questionError" class="sign-up-ht"></div>
        </td>
```

Please help me to write a step for this.

I have step definition for the same as

```
When /^I select "(.*)" from "(.*)"$/ do |value, field|
  select(value, :from => field) 
end
```

and i am writing this as

```
I select "grandfather middle name" from "user_detail[secret_question]"
```

But it is giving me error while running features as

```
Could not find field labeled "user_detail[secret_question]" (Webrat::NotFoundError)
```

Suggest any way.

Answer (score 2):

Webrat is expecting a `<label>` tag. You should make that too. You should also be able to reference the `<select>` element by using the `id`-attribute.

As a side note: Using HTML names inside your cucumber features is not done. See [Dan North's post](http://dannorth.net/2011/01/31/whose-domain-is-it-anyway/) on that.